# Why did my LibreOffice icons change and how to I get the old ones back

Tags: unity, 13.10, libreoffice

LibreOffice now has the icons in this [screenshot](http://ubuntuone.com/2YCQNpJ9svGYjuxnStOD6t) and I don't like them, I checkmarked everything in the software center for all libreoffice apps. When I saw the look I started to look for names that could have caused this weird look, but I failed. I opened terminal and uninstalled all LibreOffice apps and LibreOffice, then I installed LibreOffice again and the icons are still there. Any suggestion besides re-installing the OS (Ubuntu 13.10) because these icons are really annoying and I do not feel at home in Ubuntu with crazy office icons. THanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The icons you see are from the package **libreoffice-style-oxygen**.

Others you can install, including some that should be installed by default, are:

1. libreoffice-style-crystal
2. libreoffice-style-galaxy
3. libreoffice-style-hicontrast
4. libreoffice-style-human
5. libreoffice-style-tango ( and last but not least, the new and probably the best ;-)
6. **libreoffice-style-sifr**

These can be found in **Software Center** by entering "*libreoffice-style*" in the Search box (at the top-right corner).

You can select them from the LO menu:

**Tools** > **Options...** > **View** > **User Interface** : **Icon size and style**

Uninstalling a "libreoffice-style-*" package removes that icon style from those options.

Comment: It should also be added that since LibreOffice 4.2 they added the new icon theme Sifr. They can be easily installed with the package called: libreoffice-style-sifr. I personally think this is the most beautiful one!

Comment: My view > UI > icon size style -list has only Galaxy and Breeze, even if I installed tango and sifr. How to get them visible?

Comment: @lahjaton_j : You can check if there's no installation problem by going to `/usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/` and checking files `images_xxx.zip` which should include the names of all styles (xxx) installed. If there appears to be a problem, you might like to reinstall that package or (as a last resort) merely download it and use archive manager to open and copy the appropriate zip file either to that location or to `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/config/styles/`...

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be fixed with reboot. Maybe there was an instance of LibreOffice running somewhere that I did not notice.